# Plot don't refresh when slider updated matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, interaction

I can't figure out why the plot don't refresh when the slider is updated.
I'm using Jupiter notebook and I choose the backend with 'nbAgg' parameter.

Initialization code :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib import use as m_use
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider

m_use('nbAgg')
x1 = np.random.normal(-2.5, 1, 10000)
x2 = np.random.gamma(2, 1.5, 10000)
x3 = np.random.exponential(2, 10000)+7
x4 = np.random.uniform(14,20, 10000)
fig, ((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4)) = plt.subplots(2, 2,figsize=(7, 5))
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.1,right=.8)
```

There is a animation which lunch this function :

```
def updateData(curr,divider=7):
    global ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4
    for ax in (ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4):
        ax.cla()
    if curr <= 679 :
        my_b = int(np.around(curr/divider)+3)
    else : my_b = 100
    
    multi = 100
    ax1.hist(x1[:curr*multi],bins=my_b)
    ax2.hist(x2[:curr*multi],bins=my_b)
    ax3.hist(x3[:curr*multi],bins=my_b)
    ax4.hist(x4[:curr*multi],bins=my_b)
    fig.suptitle('Frame {} on 100'.format((curr+1)))
    return None
```

The animation :

```
simulation = animation.FuncAnimation(fig=fig, func=updateData, frames=10,
                                     blit=False, interval=1, repeat=False)
```

Here the slider which stuck me :

```
slider_ax = plt.axes([.9, 0.45, 0.01, 0.3])
slider = Slider(ax=slider_ax,label='Divider \nfor bins',valmin=1,valmax=15, valinit=7, orientation='vertical',valfmt='%.0f',track_color='black',facecolor='red',
                  handle_style={'facecolor':'k','edgecolor':'#86a2cf','size':20})
def update():
    
    anim_2 = animation.FuncAnimation(fig=fig, func=updateData, frames=20,
                                     blit=False, interval=1, repeat=False)
```

This below function don't work as expected :

```
slider.on_changed(update)

simulation = animation.FuncAnimation(fig=fig, func=updateData, frames=10,
                                     blit=False, interval=1, repeat=False)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you expect to happen when the slider is updated?

Comment: There is an event trigger `my_slider.on_changed(update)` which don't response as expected. When the slider is changed, it should restart the animation with the function `update()` but nothing happened.

Comment: What's the priority: animation, the slider inside the figure or both? Because if you are okay with slider being outside the figure, I can try to provide a solution using `ipywidgets`.

Comment: If the slider is outside, is just inside the code. I mean, this behavior don't change te functionality. Please provide this answer !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider
from ipywidgets import interact
import ipywidgets as widget

%matplotlib widget

x1 = np.random.normal(-2.5, 1, 10000)
x2 = np.random.gamma(2, 1.5, 10000)
x3 = np.random.exponential(2, 10000) + 7
x4 = np.random.uniform(14, 20, 10000)
(fig, ((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4))) = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(7, 5))
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.1, right=.8)

divider = 7
```

```
def updateData(curr):
    global ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4, divider
    for ax in (ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4):
        ax.cla()
    if (curr <= 679):
        my_b = int(np.around(curr / divider) + 3)
    else:
        my_b = 100

    multi = 100
    ax1.hist(x1[:curr * multi], bins=my_b)
    ax2.hist(x2[:curr * multi], bins=my_b)
    ax3.hist(x3[:curr * multi], bins=my_b)
    ax4.hist(x4[:curr * multi], bins=my_b)
    fig.suptitle('Frame {} on 100'.format(curr + 1))
    plt.tight_layout()

def update(val):
    global divider
    divider = val
    anim_2 = animation.FuncAnimation(fig=fig, func=updateData, frames=20, blit=False, interval=1, repeat=False)
    fig.canvas.draw()

slider = interact(update, val=widget.IntSlider(min=1, max=15, value=7))

simulation = animation.FuncAnimation(fig=fig, func=updateData, frames=10, blit=False, interval=1,repeat=False)

display(slider)
```

**Few things to note:**

- To plot interactive figures in Jupyter Notebook with matplotlib, you will need to install [`ipympl`](https://github.com/matplotlib/ipympl) after which you can plot interactive Matplotlib figures in Jupyter Notebook using the magic function `%matplotlib widget`.
- To update the figure once animation is stored in a variable, you'll need to call [`fig.canvas.draw()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.draw.html) to redraw the figure.
- Your implementation wasn't using (updated) slider value as an argument for the function `update` since `update` didn't require any argument to work. However, widgets are often use to call function with argument(s). For example, check how [interact](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Using%20Interact.html) provides an interface in Jupyter Notebook to call a same function with different values of arguments.

  Given this, I modified the `update` function which takes slider value to update the value of global variable `divider`.

This means, when calling a function `updateData` using `FuncAnimation` with `frames` as an integer, `updateData` will be invoked repeatedly with values from `range(frames)`. This means, on every invocation of `updateData` by `FuncAnimation`, `curr` will take a value from `range(frames)`.

Comment: I used `interact` because it easily works with IPython widgets and it failed to work with matplotlib widgets in Jupyter Notebook. I also checked [mpl-interactions](https://mpl-interactions.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) but couldn't figure out how to bind animation with widget it since I was using `widget` as a backend (because of `%matplotlib widget` provided by ipympl package).

Comment: +++ The part on interaction is understood and it's worked fine on other interactive scripts.
+++ I tried `fig.canvas.draw()` with the animation but it really slowed down the animation, so I deleted it.
+++ It is unclear why you use `interact` but it seems to be a whole ne branch to dig into. ++++++ I now get a fixed code but not a 'WHY' answer you know.

Comment: No improvement, I just thinking it's a bug. I mean a matplotlib.animation bug.

Comment: @IdrSEK Btw, you can create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your problem  and ask a new question to understand whether it is really a matplotlib.animation bug.